# Using chokidar to load file

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, meteor

So I've been trying to use **chokidar** as a way to load in commands added in a certain folder, now given that the only documentation of **chokidar** I can find is it's github page with the only example provided being simply an alert, I've been struggling to implement this due to two issues:
I can't return any value to the main function - from what I understand this is because **chokidar** inherit from **EventEmitter**, but using a wrapper function should somehow solve this issue?
It'll probably be very complicated to work with the files being loaded within the chokidar function.

Since the program in question needs to load in the commands and parse at different points and the parsing will happen asynchronous.

So my question is simply, how would I go on about this?

Here's the code:

```
export default function(dir) {
    let chokidar = require('chokidar');
    let fs = require('fs');
    let log = console.log.bind(console);


    let watcher = chokidar.watch(dir, {
        ignored: /(^|[\/\\])\../, 
        persistent: true
    });
    let files;
    let test;
    files = "TEST"

    watcher
    .on('addDir', path => {
        log(`Directory ${path} has been found`);
    })
    .on('add', path => {
        log(`Before : ${files}`)
        test = path
        log(`After  : ${files}`)
        //require(path)
        log(`File ${path} has been found`)
    })
    .on('ready', () => {
        log(files, test)
        files = test;
        log(files, test)
    });
    log(files)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some mingling with chokidar + events, the answer was a quite easy one:

Essentially given that every event is more or less like it's own little program but who doesn't/can't directly return a value.

So instead you can emit said data required to another event who'll handle specifically.

In my case in my "main.js" file all I need to do is:

```
let events = require('events');
var loader = new events.EventEmitter();
watchdog(cmddir, (dir) => {
    loader.emit("loadcommand", dir)


loader.on('loadcommand', (file) => {
    require(file);
});
```

Here's some relevant information about event.emitters:

https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_class_eventemitter